# Second bind() call failed with license expire for Non persistence license type in Playready

Tags: drm, playready

Second bind()call failed with license expire for Non persistence license in Play ready,

I am working to support one service:

Play back sequence of service is below:

1. do WI.
2. Call Bind()--> failed with License not found
3. do LA (Acquire License).
4. call Bind() -- success
5. call commit -- success
6. call Manifest URL
7. Player tries to play the content.
8. found its encrypted.
9. Bind()--> failed with License expired.

**My Question:**

why second Bind() is failed with License expired?

License type from service provider is Non persistence.

Is there any other reason behind this for License expire?
On what bases microsoft playready will give license expired for non persistance license type?

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Nonpersistent licenses are only usable for *one playback*, not until the application is restarted. As far as the PlayReady Device Porting Kit is concerned, one playback is equal to one Drm_Reader_Bind() call. This is why your second call fails.

While the information about license persistence is public, any more in-depth information is NDA-protected and I cannot discuss it on a public website. If you need further help and can prove that you work for a PlayReady licensee, feel free to contact me for a one-on-one chat via saares@axinom.com.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your help.

Comment: On what bases microsoft playready will give license expired for non persistance license type?

Comment: i.e in my view for non persistance licenses there is no constrains with it...so ideally it should not give License expired.